# How to run a query on PostgreSQL in specified time intervals to update a score?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, typeorm

I have a PostgreSQL 13.4 database running in a GCP hosted Docker container.
A table "plans" has a json column with a key "score".

I would like to update that score based on a calculation that takes parameters from this and other tables into account. I haven't figured out the exact query to do that yet, so I can't share it.

But the general problem would be:
How can I execute that query in specified time intervals?

For example, 1x/day or every X hours etc.
The parameters to calculate the score change irregularly, potentially very often, so I want to re-calculate that score only in regular intervals.

The application runs with Next.js/TS/React and Node.js. TypeORM for the GraphQL queries, if that matters.

Comment: U can use a cron job

Comment: Ok. Was hoping to avoid that, as I'm not familiar how to set that up on Kubernetes running in GCP, but I will look into it, thank you